# Android swipe right/left on whole recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-gesture

I found a lot of examples for swipe detection on a recyclerview item. But I try to detect right/left swipe on the whole view.

There are also examples like this [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)
on how to detect swipe on views like layout container. But attaching this touch listener to the recyclerview is not working.

So how can I detect left / right swipe on a whole recyclerview?

**Edit for SmartSwipe Lib:**
I have tried to add the https://github.com/luckybilly/SmartSwipe Lib because the effect of swipe looks really nice.

But if I try to wrap it to the recyclerview I see no data only the swipe effect:

```
        SmartSwipe.wrap(binding.recyclerView).addConsumer(BezierBackConsumer())
            .enableHorizontal()
            .addListener(object : SimpleSwipeListener() {
                override fun onSwipeOpened(wrapper: SmartSwipeWrapper, consumer: SwipeConsumer, direction: Int) {

                }
            })
```

Attaching it to the constraint layout container has no effect at all.

**Edit 2:**
Attaching an onTouchListener to the view doesn't work for the recyclerview:

```
 view.setOnTouchListener(object : OnHorizontalSwipeListener(requireContext()) {
        override fun onRightSwipe() {
            println("Swipe right")
        }

        override fun onLeftSwipe() {
            println("Swipe left")
        }

    })
```

Attaching it to the Recyclerview leads to an exception:

```
binding.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener.....

E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter e1
    at ui.OnHorizontalSwipeListener$GestureListener.onFling(Unknown Source:2)
```

**Edit 3:** Seems to work if I add null check to the listener class like this:

```
 override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent?,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        var result = false
        try {
            if (e1 != null && e2 != null) {
                val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
                val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
....
```

But starts working only after some scrolling. trying to swipe on a new initialized fragment doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Mirco, why is not working?, touch listener is a good practice to implement swipe feature. You can share us some code and we can take a look

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the same problem, and setOnTouchListener doesn’t work with recyclerview

Comment: Hi, haven't found a good solution.

Comment: I have found this solution that works for me  https://mobikul.com/applying-touch-listener-recycler-view-can-perform-click-whole-item-view/  (I just had to put the onclick event in this code and delete from my previous position)